# How to use an embedding layer as a linear layer in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I'm currently working on a personal reimplementation of the [Transformer paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2017/file/3f5ee243547dee91fbd053c1c4a845aa-Paper.pdf) and had a question.

On page 5 in section "3.4 Embeddings and Softmax," it states:

> In our model, we share the same weight matrix between the two embedding layers and the pre-softmax linear transformation.

I've currently implemented my model to use just one embedding layer for both source and target tensors, but I'm wondering if there would be a way that I could use the weights of the embedding layer as a linear layer. What I've currently done is something like:

```
output = previous_layer(previous_input)
final_output = torch.matmul(output, embedding_layer.embedding.weight.transpose(1, 0))
```

I've transposed the weight matrix before matrix multiplication because it's of shape `(vocab_size, embedding_dim)` and the shape of `output` is `(batch_size, seq_len, embedding_dim)`. Is this the proper way to use an embedding layer as a linear layer? If not, I'd like some tips on what I should be doing.

Thanks.

#### Edit

[Specific line for weight sharing from link in answer](https://github.com/jadore801120/attention-is-all-you-need-pytorch/blob/fec78a687210851f055f792d45300d27cc60ae41/transformer/Models.py#L155).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a `nn.Linear` layer and replace its weights by copying the weights from the `nn.Embedding`:

```
trg_emb = nn.Embedding(trg_enc_dim, embedding_dim)
src_emb = nn.Embedding(src_enc_dim, embedding_dim)

trg_projection = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, trg_enc_dim, bias=False)
trg_projection.weight = trg_emb.weight # copy to nn.Linear
```

You can also copy to the source embedding so your two embedding layers share the same weights as well.

```
src_emb.weight = trg_emb.weight
```

This would mean the source embedding would end up having the same size as the target embedding i.e. `trg_enc_dim x embedding_dim`.

Here's a possible PyTorch [implementation](https://github.com/jadore801120/attention-is-all-you-need-pytorch/blob/fec78a687210851f055f792d45300d27cc60ae41/transformer/Models.py) for inspiration.

Comment: Are we sure that in this case the two weights are identical? Or one copies the other upon assignment?

Comment: This is effectively a reference, not a copy. Both share the same underlying weights. So if you update the weights using `trg_projection`, you will also update `trg_emb` as a result.